# Not adding event listener

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, events, jquery-events

I'm using jQuery for my codes.
I have a password input box and I want get the typed password anytime.

Here is my code:

```
<input type="password" id="newp" name="newPassword" placeholder="New Password" />
<input type="password" id="newpa" name="newPasswordAgain" placeholder="New Password Again" />

<script>
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('#newpa').on('input', () => {
        if ($('#newpa').val() != $('#newp').val()) {
            $('#newpa').css({
                border: '2px solid red'
            });
        }
    };
});
</script>
```

I'm sure its a correct code because when I enter it in the console of my browser it works, but when I reload the page it doesn't work

What can I do?

Comment: @WangLiang the user is not likely to trigger a keyup event in this field, right after the page was reloaded.

Comment: I tried it too. its not the problem because it works in the console of my browser

Comment: Just to be clear, you are talking about the case where the user has entered data into those fields already, and then reloads the page (in a browser that will fill in the already previously entered values automatically)? Then _trigger_ this event once, after you assigned the event handler. `$('#newpa').trigger('input`');

Comment: every time in start of page while I don't enter manually jQuery codes in the console of my browser

Comment: I meant what exact “reload” scenario you are talking about. Anyway, did you try what I suggested?

Comment: it means deleting console changes, yes I do and it doesn't work

Comment: @محمدحسینسرمدی please check my answer below, thanks

Comment: Code should work fine. If is not working what is different? Are the inputs dynamically added?

Comment: @محمدحسینسرمدی i have updated the as per your recent question update, have a look again, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(() => { // Updated
    
    $('#newpa').on('input', () => {
        if ($('#newpa').val() != $('#newp').val()) {
            $('#newpa').css({
                border: '2px solid red'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```css
input:focus{
        outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="password" id="newp" name="newPassword" placeholder="New Password" />
<input type="password" id="newpa" name="newPasswordAgain" placeholder="New Password Again" />
```

Comment: Whats my problem?

Comment: Sir try your answer
i am typing qq in first input and second input and its turning red !!

Comment: no it doesn't work Im trying it. I also tried using ```document.addEventListener('load', () => {...});``` and also ```document.onload = () => {...}``` !

Comment: I know. when I try it and my code in the console of browser them work, but I don't know when I reload the page them doesn't work!

Comment: No it doesn't work, I'm using "onInput" event and it must be work when I change the input text

Comment: I say when I enter my js code (jQuery code) in the console of my browser, it works successful

Comment: I use ```* { outline: none !important; } ``` in my code its not the problem too :((

Comment: share you html page, or online url, and check http://prntscr.com/10mbprn

Answer (score 0):

1. In your code there is parsing error you are missing one closing
   parenthesis.
2. The input event will be fired multiple times, not only when you
   finish typing, to handle this simple you can put an else statement.

```html
<input type="password" id="newp" name="newPassword" placeholder="New Password" />
<input type="password" id="newpa" name="newPasswordAgain" placeholder="New Password Again" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('#newpa').on('input', () => {
        if ($('#newpa').val() != $('#newp').val()) {
            $('#newpa').css({
                border: '2px solid red'
            });
        } else {
            $('#newpa').css({
                border: '2px solid rgb(118, 118, 118)'
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: please read the last answer before your answer, I tried it too, I tried it without "ready" event function... I say in start time it doesn't work while I enter my codes in console of my browser

Comment: which browser you are trying to execute into, can you 1st confirm whether it works in browser or  not, i don't mean that you need to remove "load" neither i have removed my answer contains "load" event.

Comment: You should not use $(document).on('load', handler) instead you can use $(window).on('load', handler)

Comment: I say I tried your answer, and *also* I tried without "load" event function

Comment: I change my question look that please